# How To Restrict Access To Custom WordPress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, template-redirect

I have a custom template that I built which manages a separate table inside a WordPress database.  I have had success restricting access unless logged in on all other pages (including existing custom templates) accept my custom template (page id 9597) using this code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_restrict_access');
  function add_restrict_access(){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 9597 ) ) {
    wp_redirect( '/wp-login.php' );
    exit;
  }
}
```

If I change the is_page number to any other page ID, the redirect works.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing the full details, the only thing that comes to mind is that ID 9597 is not a 
"page" post type. Is it a custom post type or a "post" post type?

Comment: The body tag has this:

class="page-template page-template-template-history-management page-template-template-history-management-php page page-id-9597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL cert issue.  Page was viewable without SSL, as soon as I added https it started working properly.  Weird.